# probablity review questions.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

1. A jar contains 7 red balls and 9 blue balls. We choose, uniformly at random and without
   replacement, 5 balls. Let A be the event
   A = “exactly 2 of the balls are red or exactly 3 of the balls are blue”.
   What is Pr(A)?

a) $\binom{7}{2} \over \binom{16}{5}$

b) $2\times\binom{7}{2}\binom{9}{3} \over \binom{16}{5}$

c) $\binom{7}{2}\binom{9}{3} \over \binom{16}{5}$

d) $\binom{7}{2}+\binom{9}{3} \over \binom{16}{5}$

I thought this question was c) because u choose exactly 2 red balls or 3 blue balls out of the 5 balls that we have to choose. the pr(a) or pr(b) I thought the formula for it was pr(a)*pr(b) so c)

can anyone explain why is it d)?

Comment: I would go with c). If we consider R={exactly 2 out of 5 balls are red} and B={exactly 3 out of 5 balls are blue}, then R=B. So, A=R=B.

Comment: The correct answer is c). Did anyone tell you that d) is the correct answer? Btw, if exactly $2$ of the $5$ balls are red then *automatically* $3$ of the $5$ balls are *not red*, i.e. are blue here.

Answer (score 0):

You were correct to choose c) but for the wrong reason. The only reason that the solution given would be d) is that the person setting the problem stuffed up.

Event $A$ is described as “exactly 2 of the balls are red or exactly 3 of the balls are blue”. It is a logical (not a probabilistic) argument that the first part of the predicate (“exactly 2 of the balls are red") can be true if and only if the second part is also true ("exactly 3 of the balls are blue”).

So you are dealing with 1 event not 2. This immediately eliminates answers b) and d). Deciding between the remaining 2 is easy if you recognize this a [Hypergeometric Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Even without knowing this a) accounts for the 2 that are blue but ignores the 3 that are red c) covers both and is therefore correct.

Combining probabilities follows the following equations:

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B|A)=P(B)P(A|B)$$

Your statement that $P(A\cup B)=P(A)P(B)$ is wrong because:

1. You actually need $P(A\cap B)$
2. $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent, or equivalently, $P(A|B)=P(A)$ and $P(B|A)=P(B)$. In this case they are *highly* dependent becuase they are the same!